# array_push inside function produces error "expects parameter 1 to be array, null given.."

Tags: php

Why am I getting this error message "Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given ..." When I removed the function and just run the for loop, it works, but not inside function. why?

```
<?php

$arr = array();
function callme() {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        array_push($arr, $x);
    }
    return $arr;
}

callme();

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare array `$arr` as global

```
$arr = array();
function callme() {
    global $arr;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        array_push($arr, $x);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Or pass `$arr` as a parameter.

Comment: I also tried global but didn't work. Turns out we need to define an array before the function too. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do either of two things:

Add $array as function parameter and return that.

```
<?php

$arr = array();
function callme($array) {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        array_push($array, $x);
    }
    return $array;
}

$arr = callme($arr);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

If you don't like returns you can have the array as reference...

```
<?php

$arr = array();
function callme(&$array) {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        array_push($array, $x);
    };
}

callme($arr);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

or define $arr als global in the function(least desired, you're stuck with only one array)

```
<?php

$arr = array();
function callme() {
    global $arr;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        array_push($arr, $x);
    }
    return $arr;
}

callme();

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Comment: don't forget `function callme() use(&$arr) {`, though in this case that's not much better than global.

Comment: well... seeing his level of understanding that wouldn't be wise... I doubted about using references but decided to add that...
Sometimes I find it amazing how many ways php has to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: You might be right. Though seeing the code, I thought that he might come from a javascript background (closures), and `use` is probably the closest to this.

Comment: Even in javascript it's tricky to use globals... if you ever need a global in javascript one always need to use the window reference to initiate the variable otherwise you'll never reliably know where the variable will end up and you'll encounter a myriad of problems...

the use(&$arr) is for most javascript programmers a bridge to far though... references are tough enough to understand for some people,  and to add another scoping parameter that looks like a function to a function is difficult to understand for most..
Plus using globals sucks big time, difficult to track and stuff......

Comment: In javascript, same as in php using `use`, it' wouldn't necessarily be a global. Just in this special case it's basicially the same as using `global`. In other cases, say class methods for example, `use` has it's use. ;)

Comment: use certainly has it's usefullness, but when to use the use is a matter of usability and usefullness. Because if you use use for easy using, you might not be using use for the right uses.

Answer (score 0):

Someone needs to learn some basics about variable scopes.

http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php